# How to reset Office UI Fabric Dropdown

Tags: web-part, spfx, react, dropdown, office-ui-fabric-react

My  this.handleReset() does not working. Any idea, why?

```
<Dropdown options={this.state.options}
                  placeholder= "Bitte wählen..."
                  onChange={ this.handleChange }
                  required= {true}/>

<DefaultButton className={styles.btn2} onClick={()=> this.clearForm()}> Abbrechen </DefaultButton>

 handleChange = (event: FormEvent<HTMLDivElement>, option: IDropdownOption): void => {
console.log("Selected Option: " + option.text)
this.setState({
  selectedOption: option.text,
  selectedValue: option.key.toString()
});

handleReset = () => {
this.setState({ selectedOption: "" });

public clearForm= (): void =>  {
this.handleReset();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not telling the drop down which is its `selectedKey`.

```
<Dropdown
    options={this.state.options}
    placeholder= "Bitte wählen..."
    onChange={ this.handleChange }
    selectedKey={this.state.selectedOption} <- This line is missing
    required= {true}
/>
```

Since you are not telling the component which is its "SelectedKey" it won't detect if you empty the state in your "handleReset" function.

Comment: Thank you!

Now I have an other Problem. The placeholder stays everytime "Bitte wählen" and does not change to the selectedOption. Any idea, why? Without selectedKey = {this.state.selectedOptions} is right, but it cant be reseted...

Comment: Are you sure that the value of your SelectedKey is actually a "key" and no the "text". Check your UpdateState function: this.setState({
  selectedOption: **option.key**,
  selectedValue: option.key.toString()
});